# Luke 4.6.1 FormatTooNew error?

Tags: lucene, luke

So I'm trying to use Luke for the first time and I'm having some trouble.  I point it to the directory I want, but see this:

org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource: SimpleFSIndexInput(path="C:\Users*me*\Chat Data\chat-data\index\segments.gen")): -3 (needs to be between -2 and -2)

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Is it a compatibility issue?  I'm lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are using a version of Luke which is too old for your index.

You can get a newer version from https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases/.